# Building with Boost through Visual Studio is not picking the correct VS version or statically linked libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, boost

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Error   2   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib'

This isn't a pathing problem.  I intentionally do not have that .lib built, and want to link against the mt-sgd-1_38.lib file, but I don't know what I need to set to have boost's auto-naming select the mt-sgd instead of mt-gd.

Also, I'm not sure how it's detecting to use vc90, but I'm attempting to build with VS 2005, which is vc80.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that flag ('s') is indicative of static linking; ie: linking the c-runtime libraries statically. It would be a project setting for you app.

Also, for the v80/v90 issue, I have had similar when I had the v90 compiler installed with some part of the platform SDK. If you're getting v90 in the linker object name, chances are you're actually building with the v90 compiler (which is possible within the 2005 IDE, depending on path settings and what's installed). Shouldn't be an issue, as long as everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC to the preprocessor, I've used this previously to figure out problems such as these, however I've usually had the opposite problem.  It tries static and I want dynamic, I fixed that last time by adding BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL, there must be other equivalents - I assume you just substitute THREAD for the name of the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using this option when building: runtime-link=static, as in

```
.\b2 runtime-link=static
```

Comment: What's the rest of the context needed to get that to work? I get: "'.\b2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." when I try to run ".\b2 ..." using the VS 2017 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt from my /boost directory.